# Configure position of window for cv::imshow

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Is there a way to change the position of the window that pops up when `cv::imshow` is called?

For me, the window seems to appear partially off-screen, so I have to drag it around before I can see entire image.  It's very annoying to have to do this every single time.

I had a look at the reference manual -- it seems you have control over what goes into the title of the window, but I can't see anything relating to window position.

Oh, and the behavior is the same if I use the old C interface (`cvShowImage`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<del>Using C++ API it is not possible at the moment.</del>

<del>You can use C API instead; it is [`cvMoveWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow).</del>

**UPDATE:** Now it is possible in C++ with [`cv::moveWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow)

Comment: updated link:
[cv::moveWindow()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=movewindow#movewindow)

Answer (score 21):

As of OpenCV 2.1 this is possible also in C++ API using the [moveWindow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow) function:

```
cv::moveWindow(std::string winName, int x, int y)
```

For example:

```
cv::namedWindow("WindowName");
cv::moveWindow("WindowName", 10, 50);
```

Comment: At least in 2.3 (!) you still have to use the C function `cvMoveWindow` to do that, cf. http://docs.opencv.org/2.3/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html. In the C++ API this was added later.

Comment: It always gets me, that you have to call the namedWindow() functor first.